# Firefox profiel doesn't work with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to use `Firefox Profile` to set some preferences of the browser. I am using it with the help of this plugin https://github.com/saadtazi/firefox-profile-js and webdriver IO.

Like that

```
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile'),
    webdriver = require('webdriverio');

var fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
fp.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/save/file/to/this/directory");
fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml, application/csv, text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream");

fp.encoded(function(prof) {

    var client = webdriver.remote({
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'firefox',
            firefox_profile: prof
        },
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 4444
    });

    client
        .init()
        .url('http://google.com')
        .pause(2000)
        .end();

});
```

And changing the order of preferences doesn't work either.

```
    fp.encoded(function(prof) {

    var client = webdriver.remote({
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'firefox',

        },
       firefox_profile: prof,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 4444
    });
```

Also moving options to the init call doesn't work.

I remember that some time ago I managed to use profile, but now it doesn't work.

I am using `standalone-firefox-debug:3.5.3-astatine`

How to get it working ?

Comment: I have the similar problem, no matter what i set in the profile, it fails to reflect in the firefox.

Btw, suppose the first argument is error and second one is zippedProfile for method fp.encoded.

Also you have missed fp.updatePreferences() before encoded.